# How to get when windows has booted in C++

Tags: c++, windows, gettickcount

I am working in a C++ application where I need to check the timing when OS has booted.
Is there any way to retrieve that time?

I tried GetTickCount64() function but it is returning the time when my exe has started.
ULONGLONG tm = GetTickCount64();

I would like to know when windows has booted.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of how you're using the value returned from `GetTickCount64`? I don't believe it is broken but it's possible how you're using it is incorrect.

Comment: What does it mean that "windows has booted"?  Do you mean time since power-on?  Or time since all of Windows startup routined finished executing and the system was idle and ready for use?  Or something else?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I am looking for the time since the power is on.

Comment: Hmm, the GetTickCount64() function is documented as "Retrieves the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started", which is pretty unambiguous; so if that isn't the behavior you are seeing from that function, something quite strange must be going on.